# TypeScript InstanceType with Generic Parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm building a library which allows a consumer to provide it with a constructor/class, an instance of which will form one of its public members.

For a simple, non-generic class this works fine and we get accurate inferred intellisense and type safety on the library instance's public interface:

```js
class MyLibrary<TNewable extends new (...args: any[]) => any> {
    public foo: InstanceType<TNewable>;

    constructor(ConsumerNewable: TNewable) {
        this.foo = new ConsumerNewable();
    }
}

class ConsumerProvidedClass {}

const library = new MyLibrary(ConsumerProvidedClass);

library.foo // type: ConsumerProvidedClass
```

Now consider the scenario that `ConsumerProvidedClass` has itself one generic parameter which defines some aspect of its behaviour. It's not important for the question but the actual use-case is an RxJS `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` where `TThroughput` is the observable's throughput type. So, for example:

```js
class ConsumerProvidedClass<TThroughput> { ... }
```

The library is now extended to allow the consumer to provide an "initial value" of type `TModel` which will be passed to `ConsumerProvidedClass` on instantiation, and also become its throughput type:

```js
class MyLibrary<TNewable extends new (...args: any[]) => any, TModel> {
    public foo: InstanceType<TNewable>;

    constructor(ConsumerNewable: TNewable, initialValue: TModel) {
        this.foo = new ConsumerNewable(initialValue);
    }
}

class ConsumerProvidedClass<TThroughput> {}

class ConsumerProvidedModel {}

const library = new MyLibrary(ConsumerProvidedClass, new ConsumerProvidedModel());

library.foo // type: ConsumerProvidedClass<{}>
```

The problem is that intellisense on property `.foo` correctly infers `ConsumerProvidedClass` but *does not know* about its generic throughput type, and falls back to `<{}>`.

What I would like to see is:

```js
library.foo // type: ConsumerProvidedClass<ConsumerProvidedModel>
```

But this would rely on being able to provide `TModel` to `InstanceType<TNewable>` as a generic parameter. I have not been able to find any information on how to do this, or if indeed it is possible at all. Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```js
public foo: (InstanceType<TNewable>)<TModel>;
```

But unfortunately this is not valid TypeScript.

Of course I could have the consumer explicitly pass all generic types when they instantiate the library, but I would much prefer that everything is inferred where possible for a better developer experience.

Any insights much appreciated. Perhaps there is another way of approaching this that I am missing.

Comment: My guess is that this is not possible because you don't have a way to declare `TNewable` is a generic type taking `TModel`.

Comment: TypeScript lacks the [higher-kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) necessary to represent what you're looking for, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok thanks - I guess I'm in feature request territory then.